# Get-IAMUser PolicyList returning empty list for new account

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-iam

I'm creating a process to create a AWS new account within my org via the powershell AWS module. This process then attaches a new policy to the svc account to manage that new account.

The problem Im finding is after creating the new policy (and waiting for that policy to be created), I attach it to the account, then try (after waiting again) to query that it has attached. The policy list is returned empty. When I check in the AWS console, the policy is attached but this is supposed to be an automated process and I can't confirm that it has worked to continue the process.

The Code calling the api (which might be the wrong end point) is:

`$attachedPolicy = Get-IAMUserPolicyList -ProfileName $sourceAccountProfile -UserName $username`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes when you attach a policy to an IAM user or Role it takes a while until it can be used. Maybe you just need to have a timer to have this process take full effect.

Comment: I have got a 2min timer built into the process but the query is still returning null after a day. Also when I look at the console the role has been attached but the Get-IAMUserPolicyList query is returning nothing (meaning it doesn't think it is attached